# Create empty object and set its attribute to something

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an action in my controller called `update_models` where I set an instance variable called `@selected_model` based on the value of `params[:model_id]`:

```
def update_models
  if params[:model_id].blank?
    // create object with id attribute equals '0'.
  else
    @selected_model = Model.find(params[:model_id]
  end
end
```

In the first part of the if statement, how can I assign `@selected_model` an empty object and set its `id` attribute to `'0'`, so that I can access that attribute in my view using `@selected_model.id`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that params is **not nil**

```
def update_models
  @selected_model = Model.find_by_id( params[:model_id] ) || Model.new( id: 0 )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do this?

```
def update_models
  if params[:model_id].blank?
    @selected_model = Model.new
    @selected_model.id = 0
  else
    @selected_model = Model.find(params[:model_id]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like (with no `if` condition):

```
def update_models
  @selected_model = Model.find(params[:model_id])
rescue
  @selected_model = Model.new
  @selected_model.id = 0
end
```